# How to get current window in shared app extensions?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, imessage-extension

I am working on **iMessage** app extension, I need to get app window in this extension for some reasons. Previously I was doing like this as mentioned bellow :-
`guard let currentWindow : UIWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else {return}`

in xcode 12 it was  working perfectly. On the other hand after updating to 12.5.1 , this started giving me error for the same code.
As follow :- [image]

Secondly, I am not able to call `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl)`
[image]

Comment: That seems to be a frequently asked question. Have you checked these Q&As? https://www.google.de/search?q=shared%27+is+unavailable+in+application+extensions+for+ios+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Yes I checked, but don't get any luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this to test access to `UIApplication.shared` from your extension:

```
guard UIApplication.responds(to: NSSelectorFromString("sharedApplication")) else {
    return
}
let shared = UIApplication.perform(NSSelectorFromString("sharedApplication"))?.takeUnretainedValue() as? UIApplication
```

By using `perform`, you ignore the compiler and determine your call at runtime.

Be aware that this might not work in your extension. There is a reason why the API doesn't allow you to access it by default from your extension, even when it works fine from a normal app.

Same goes for your call to `UIApplication.shared.open`.

So in the end, you probably can't use `UIApplication.shared`. The key difference is extension vs. app.